# Netty4: IdleStateHandler doesn't fire event in EmbeddedChannel

Tags: netty

I want to test the IdleStateHandler in a EmbeddedChannel, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
public class IdleStateHandlerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new IdleStateHandler(1, 0, 0), new MyInHandler());
        while (true) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println(".");
        }
    }

    private static class MyInHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("event: " + evt);
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected is an output like "event: xxxx". But It doesn't print this message. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `channel.runPendingTasks()` periodically as `EmbeddedChannel` will just execute everything in the calling thread and so will only run scheduled tasks when you explicit tell it.